# TIF image displayed in greyscale

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, arcscene

In ArcMap 10.8.2 I export my current map view as a TIF image. I select "Write World File" and Format "24-bit True Color".
I then import this TIF file into ArcScene. But it always ends up being greyscaled. The original map is colored and when I look at the TIF file with another application, it is also colored. But the imported file in ArcScene adds three bands, each having white to black scale. When I look at tutorials, when they import their TIF files, they end up having red, green and blue symbols next to their TIF bands. Which setting do I need, to import a TIF as colored map and not being greyscaled?

How it looks when I import:
[image]

how it should look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ArcScene has an issue with RGB colors when importing, but not with 8 bit colormaps. I have solved the problem by changing the colormode of the image. I opened the TIF file in Photoshop and switched from RGB to indexed color and thus, reducing its colors to 256 colors. I save this file and on import in ArcScene it is now colored.